# How to call a dll created from .net core console app using .NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to start a process by calling a dll created from .NET Core (2.1) console app from .NET Core API. I tried this using creating a process. The following shows the code.

```
            string filePath = @"C:\Projects\MyProject.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\"; 

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "dotnet",
                WorkingDirectory = filePath,
                Arguments = "ReportGeneratorApp.dll",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                RedirectStandardError = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start(); // process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

And in the ReportGeneratorApp main method I'm trying to create a file in the file system.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
        }

        string path = @"D:\MyTest.txt";
        Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {

            // Delete the file if it exists.
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }

            // Create the file.
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
            {
                byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file." + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }

            // Open the stream and read it back.
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the ReportGeneratorApp from cmd it does work. But not when i call it from web api. Any clues?

Comment: Web api is being run on IIS or some other hosting service. Usually, those hosting apps run your web apis and apps with lowest permissions possible. So, IIS user might just lack access rights to write to that D drive.

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a silly mistake by addding a Console.ReadLine() in my program. So it won't run from that point onwards. I had to remove it in order to work.

Also I made some change in the code where i call the process to start. I need to call the waitforexit() method until I receive the response from the program.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "dotnet",
                WorkingDirectory = fileDirectoryPath,
                Arguments = "ReportGeneratorApp.dll",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;

                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                var output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
```